# HttpResponseMessage content is being returned as unicode

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to read the contents of a `HttpResponseMessage` message as a string. However, it appears to be being returned as unicode.

This is my code that I am using to make the request with `HttpClient`

```
 var responseMsg = await httpClient
                        .SendAsync(requestMsg, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead)
                        .ConfigureAwait(false);
                    return await BuildResponse(responseMsg, cookieContainer.GetAllCookies().ToList()).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

And here is my code for `BuildResponse`

```
private static async Task<IResponse> BuildResponse(HttpResponseMessage responseMsg, List<Cookie> cookies)
    {
        Ensure.ArgumentNotNull(responseMsg, nameof(responseMsg));

        // We only support text stuff for now
        using var content = responseMsg.Content;
        var headers = responseMsg.Headers.ToDictionary(header => header.Key, header => header.Value.First());
        var body = await responseMsg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        var contentType = content.Headers?.ContentType?.MediaType;

        return new Response(headers)
        {
            ContentType = contentType,
            StatusCode = responseMsg.StatusCode,
            Body = body,
            CookieCollection = cookies
        };
    }
```

[image]

I know that the API call is working correctly, as I can see the exact request in fiddler return the JSON I am expecting:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I should get the JSON returned as shown in screenshot 2.

Comment: Could you show the real buildresponse code, not img  pls?

Comment: @Sergey updated - thank you.

Comment: Are you sure it's unicode? Could it just be compressed?

Comment: Which headers do you have in response?

Answer (score 0):

try to check your response data:

```
var body = await responseMsg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var data= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<your response data class>(body);
```